# Retrieve hierarchy based on node property with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes in my graph where they are in a hierarchy. The hierarchy is saved as a node property instead of edges. There are no connecting edges between these nodes in the graph.

eg:

```
P1 -CHILD-> P2, P3 -CHILD-> P4
P1 has Node property: Child - [P2,P3,P4]
P2 has Node property: Child - [P4]
P3 has Node property: Child - [P4]
P4 has Node property: Child - None
```

Is it possible to retrieve all the hierarchy starting from P1 in a cypher query?

Comment: 1. In your example, is `P4`  actually a _child_ of `P1`, or just a _grandchild_? Your existing data model may be ambiguous. 2. Is this a Cypher question, or a more limited opencypher question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take advantage of the power of a graph database, your graph should have relationships. Create them with this query.

```
MATCH (n)
UNWIND n.child AS child
MATCH (ch {name:child})
CREATE (n)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(ch)
```

Then you can return the full hierarchy with this query.

```
MATCH path = (n {name:"P1"})-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(ch)
RETURN [p in nodes(path) | p.name] AS pathToChild
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using ORDPATH for sorting in hierarchical order. There is a Neo4j user defined function for this described at
https://www.wai.md/post/ordpath-computing-genealogy-descendancy-trees

During graph traversals you can collect numeric values and then call the function to get the concatenated bitstring which sorts hierarchically.